# Do there exist rational numbers $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt[4]{2}=a+b\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Do there exist rational numbers $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt[4]{2}=a+b\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$?

I am pretty sure that there do not but I cannot figure out how to show such. I have tried manipulating this equation in order to get it into a form that shows nonexistence but I have not been fruitful. Is there a different perspective that I should be looking at this with? This is my first time working with a problem such as this one.

Comment: Do you know much [tag:field-theory]? Particularly the theory of algebraic field extensions. The tools from there work here, but if that will be all Greek to you ... :-)

Comment: You could use the fact that $x^4 - 2$ is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[4]{2}$. That means, among other things, that a fourth-order polynomial with rational coefficients only has $\sqrt[4]{2}$ as a root if it is a constant multiple of $x^4-2$.

Comment: $a=0$ by applying the automorphism sending $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to $-\sqrt[4]{2}$, then the result is obvious.

Comment: The minimal polynomials of $\sqrt[4]2$ and $\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$ are $x^4-2$ and $x^4-2x^2-1$ respectively. It follows $$\sqrt[4]2\notin\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}\right)$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume there exist, raise to the square both sides and get
$$\sqrt{2} = a^2 + b^2(1+ \sqrt{2}) + 2 a b \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$$

Assume first that $a b \ne 0$ and get

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} = c + d \sqrt{2}$$
for some rational $c$, $d$, and so
$$1+ \sqrt{2}= (c+d\sqrt{2})^2$$

Separating the rational and irrational parts conclude that we also have
$$1- \sqrt{2}= (c- d \sqrt{2})^2$$
and that is not possible.

We have the case $a b = 0$. Clearly cannot have $b=0$, so $a=0$ and
$$\sqrt[4]{2} = b \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{2}}$$
or
$$\frac{1+ \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{b^2}$$
again not possible.

$\bf{Added:}$ A general statement is that incommensurable (square) roots are linearly independent. That is, if $d_i \in F$ field ( of characteristic $\ne 2$),  $\sqrt{d_i} \in K\supset F$, and $\frac{\sqrt{d_i}}{\sqrt{d_j}}\not \in F$ for $i\ne j$, then $(\sqrt{d_i})_i$ are linearly independent over $F$ (in our case $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$).